# How do I write a query to find highest earning day per quarter?

Tags: sql

I need to write SQL query to pull the single, highest-earning day for a certain brand of each quarter of 2018. I have the following but it does not pull a singular day - it pulls the highest earnings for each day.

```
select distinct quarter, order_event_date, max(gc) as highest_day_gc
from (
    select sum(commission) as cm, order_date,
        extract(quarter from order__date) as quarter
    from order_table
    where advertiser_id ='123'
    and event_year='2018'
    group by 3,2
)
group by 1,2
order by 2 DESC
```

Comment: That won't even work without a table alias on your sub-query. And you can't group by ordinal value, and even if you could you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to find the highest earning day per quarter by using `rank()`.

```
select rank() over (partition by quarter order by gc desc) as rank, quarter, order_event_date, gc
from (select sum(gross_commission) gc,
             order_event_date,
             extract(quarter from order_event_date) quarter
      from order_aggregation
      where advertiser_id = '123'
        and event_year = '2018'
      group by order_event_date, quarter) a
```

You could create the query above as *view* and filter it by using `where rank = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the LIMIT clause at the end of the sentence. Also, change the las ORDER BY clause to ORDER BY highest_day_gc. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT quarter
               ,order_event_date
               ,max(gc) as highest_day_gc
FROM    (SELECT sum(gross_commission) as gc
               ,order_event_date
               ,extract(quarter from order_event_date) as quarter
         FROM order_aggregation
         WHERE advertiser_id ='123'
               AND event_year='2018'
         GROUP BY 3,2) as subquery
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I could use that if I only needed 1 quarter but I need the highest for each of the 4 quarters

Comment: Then you might need to use window functions. Window functions help making partitions in your orderings. One of the answers already brought up one of the most commons window functions: the rank() function.